# How do I refactor my function?

Tags: reactjs

I have this function that is in each page of my `react-router` app.

```
  submitForm(e) {
    const redirect = this.props.location.query.redirect;
    const age = this.refs.age.value;

    const gender = this.refs.gender.value;

    const ethnicity = this.refs.ethnicity.value;

    if (!age || !gender || !ethnicity) {
      this.props.dispatch(
        showError({
          type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
          modalType: 'SHOW_ERROR',
          modalProps: {
            onClose: hideModal,
            text: 'Please complete all fields',
          },
        })
      );
    } else {
      this.props.dispatch(addDetails(age, gender, ethnicity));
      if (redirect) {
        this.props.router.push('6');
      } else {
        this.props.router.push('4');
      }
    }
  }
```

I am new to react, how can I refactor this to be passed into each component as a prop? Rather than repeat the code in each component.

Can I put it into its own `helpers` file something like this?

```
import helpers from './helpers';
import './index.css';
const store = configureStore();
console.log({ store });
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} {...helpers} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: If you already have a helper, put it inside and `export submitForm`. Then to use it: `import {submitForm} from './helpers'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You would need your helpers module to export the function (`export default submitForm(e)...`)and pass it to your component as `<Router ... sumbmitForm={helpers} />`

Your child component can then call this.props.submitForm().

You also need to make sure that you pass it down to each child component in the chain.

Comment: if you are using redux for state management then you could certainly create an action which does your function above and dispatch it from your components. Thunk is a piece of middle-ware which allows you to dispatch asynchronous actions. Your function in your question does not appear to be asynchronous and so doesn't warrant the use of thunk